# Greasemonkey + jQuery: using GM_setValue() within an event callback

Tags: jquery, events, callback, greasemonkey, storage

I'm trying to set data in long-term storage in a GreaseMonkey script, except that GM_setValue() seems to fail silently:

```
$("a#linkid").click(function()
{
    GM_setValue("foo", 123); // doesn't work, but does not generate error
});

GM_setValue("bar", 123); // works properly, value is set
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this is a specific Greasemonkey security issue.  Please see [0.7.20080121.0 compatibility](http://wiki.greasespot.net/0.7.20080121.0_compatibility).  GM does not allow user pages to call GreaseMonkey APIs, and that's what you're doing there (you're registering a click handler with JQuery running in the user context).  A workaround is also given on that page.

Comment: Umm, I am confused about why they seem to think that this security fix helped anything?
Basically did they not just fill a security whole and then tell everyone how to hack it anyways and now we have to use confusing code to do this.

Anyways, thanks I was about to ask how to call GM_setValue() from within the webpage, and this popped up, so saved me the trouble.

Comment: What I am wondering is if it is only workable because all values are predefined, or would this work:

`unsafeWindow.someObject.registerCallback(function(key, value) {
  setTimeout(function(key, value) {
    GM_setValue(key, value);
  }, 0);
});`

Comment: @JonathonWisnoski The problem isn't legitimate script writers, it's malicious website writers who could potentially embed `GM_getvalue()` in their site and dump your private data (or fake AJAX requests and impersonate you on sites where your browser has an active session). The workaround is only possible starting from an elevated (out-of-page) context.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same kind of problem...

Previous solution was not working for me and I found solution like this...

```
function gmGet(name) {
    var theValue = GM_getValue(name);
    return theValue;
}

function gmSet(name, valuee) {
    GM_setValue(name, valuee);
}

$("a#linkid").click(function(){
    //setValue
    gmSet("foo", 123);

   //getValue
   gmGet("foo");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this solution.

```
$("a#linkid").click(function()
{
    //setValue
    setTimeout(GM_setValue("foo", 123),0);

   //getValue
   setTimeout(GM_getValue("foo"),0);
});
```

Comment: Good trick, actually. Though I think you meant /*setValue*/ and /*getValue*/, the code you posted wouldn't actually run. ;)