# How can I provide a limited interface to Greasemonkey's GM_xmlhttpRequest to my page's Javascript?

Tags: javascript, security, api, greasemonkey

I have a Greasemonkey userscript which runs most of its code in an unprivileged context by inserting a `<script>` tag like so:

```
function code {
  ...
}

var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "application/javascript";
script.innerHTML = "(" + code + ")();";
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

This avoids the need to do dangerous things with `unsafeWindow`.

However, I my code needs to get information from an API on another domain which doesn't support JSONP.  `GM_xmlhttpRequest` can access other domains, but is only available in the privileged Greasemonkey context.

I'd like to write a function which provides a limited interface and makes exactly the API call I need using `GM_xmlhttpRequest`, and then expose that (theoretically safe) function to the normal page context.  My first attempt at that was something like:

```
unsafeWindow.foo = function() {
  console.log("Foo!");
  console.log(GM_xmlhttpRequest.toString());
  GM_xmlhttpRequest({
    method: "GET",
    url: "http://www.example.net/",
    headers: {
      "User-Agent": navigator.userAgent,
      "Accept": "text/html"
    },
    onload: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      unsafeWindow.console.log(response);
      alert(response);
      unsafeWindow.alert(response);
    }
  });
  console.log("Bar!");
};
```

Interestingly, when I call `foo()` from the page context, I see "Foo!", the stringified `GM_xmlhttpRequest` and "Bar!" in the console log.  However, I never get the response in the console or in an alert.  If I make the `GM_xmlhttpRequest` on its own in the GM context, I get both alerts and log messages.

The question is: is what I'm trying to do even possible?  Or is there another way to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: Why are you running your code in an unpriviledged context in the first place?

Comment: I need to interact with existing script on the page, which is painful (and unsafe) to do directly from the Greasemonkey context.  It involves a lot more unsafeWindow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha!  The answer has been posted to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860829/greasemonkey-jquery-using-gmsetvalue-within-an-event-callback).

Greasemonkey does this very intentionally, and provides a simple workaround on the [0.7.20080121.0 compatibility](http://wiki.greasespot.net/0.7.20080121.0_compatibility) page:

```
unsafeWindow.foo = function() {
  window.setTimeout(GM_xmlhttpRequest, 0, {
    // ...
  });
};
```

That works.